# Como mostrar los elementos repetidos de una tabla en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Amigos tengo la siguiente tabla llamada
**Programacion_entregas** con los siguentes campos

```
cod_entrega, cod_ordenamiento, cod_centro_atencion, cod_medicamento
```

necesito encontrar cuando haya solamente datos duplicados del medicamento.
por ejemplo

```
entrega 1, ordenamiento 1289, centroAtencion 12345, cod_medicamento 5
entrega 1, ordenamiento 1289, centroAtencion 12345, cod_medicamento 6
```

por lo general estan asi, donde el medicamento es diferente, pero necesito ubicar solamente los que tenga  el mismo odenamiento.

Estoy tratando de hacerlo asi

```
SELECT ENTRE.COD_ORDENAMIENTO, ENTRE.COD_CENTRO_ATENCION, ENTRE.COD_ENTREGA, ENTRE.COD_MEDICAMENTO,
       ENTRE2.COD_ORDENAMIENTO, ENTRE2.COD_CENTRO_ATENCION, ENTRE2.COD_ENTREGA, ENTRE2.COD_MEDICAMENTO
FROM IPS_PROGRAMACION_ENTREGAS@CONSUBAS ENTRE,
     IPS_PROGRAMACION_ENTREGAS@CONSUBAS ENTRE2
WHERE ENTRE.COD_ORDENAMIENTO = ENTRE2.COD_ORDENAMIENTO AND
 ENTRE.COD_CENTRO_ATENCION = ENTRE2.COD_CENTRO_ATENCION
AND ENTRE.COD_ENTREGA = ENTRE2.COD_ENTREGA
AND ENTRE.COD_MEDICAMENTO = ENTRE2.COD_MEDICAMENTO;
```

Pero me trae solamente los datos repetidos de la misma consulta.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: no sobra esto? AND ENTRE.COD_MEDICAMENTO = ENTRE2.COD_MEDICAMENTO;

Comment: En [Tratamiento de datos duplicados en SQL Server](https://geeks.ms/lmblanco/2015/07/06/tratamiento-de-datos-duplicados-en-sql-server-1/) tienes la información que necesitas. Habla específicamente de SQL Server, pero los consultas que te interesan son válidas para Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Sólo te daré una idea, pues no entiendo bien cuales son las columnas a las que le quieres hayar las filas repetidas. mira, sin hacer JOIN con la misma tabla puedes es encontrar filas con más de una repetición de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT COD_ORDENAMIENTO, COD_CENTRO_ATENCION, COD_ENTREGA, COD_MEDICAMENTO
FROM IPS_PROGRAMACION_ENTREGAS@CONSUBAS
GROUP BY COD_ORDENAMIENTO, COD_CENTRO_ATENCION, COD_ENTREGA, COD_MEDICAMENTO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

Si las columnas repetidas son los tres primeros puedes quitar COD_MEDICAMENTO.